# Mahout Java compilation issue

Tags: java, classpath, javac, mahout, cloudera

I am reading Mahout in Action and working through [the first example](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/master/src/main/java/mia/recommender/ch02/RecommenderIntro.java) in chapter 2.

```
$ javac RecommenderIntro.java 
RecommenderIntro.java:2: error: package org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file does not exist
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.*;
^
RecommenderIntro.java:3: error: package org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood does not exist
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.*;
^
RecommenderIntro.java:4: error: package org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender does not exist
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.*;
```

I installed Mahout via yum:

```
$ sudo yum install mahout
...
Downloading Packages:
mahout-0.7+12-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.9.el6.noarch.rpm                      |  94 MB     05:17     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Updating   : mahout-0.7+12-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.9.el6.noarch              1/2 
Cleanup    : mahout-0.7+8-1.cdh4.1.2.p0.12.el6.noarch              2/2 
Verifying  : mahout-0.7+12-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.9.el6.noarch              1/2 
Verifying  : mahout-0.7+8-1.cdh4.1.2.p0.12.el6.noarch              2/2 

Updated:
mahout.noarch 0:0.7+12-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.9.el6                                                             

Complete!
```

I am also completely brand new to Java.

Am I compiling this incorrectly?

Do I need to specify some include paths on the command line with invoking javac?

Comment: Don't you have to include the library in your Java project path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out this is simple, once you know where the jars you need are located.  In the cloudera mahout distribution they are in /usr/lib/mahout and /usr/lib/mahout/lib.

```
$ javac -cp "/usr/lib/mahout/*:/usr/lib/mahout/lib/*:." RecommenderIntro.java 
$ java -cp "/usr/lib/mahout/*:/usr/lib/mahout/lib/*:." RecommenderIntro 

RecommendedItem[item:104, value:4.257081]
```

Comment: Exactly right. I see a couple unfriendly comments pointed at me on related questions. I don't "troll" or retaliate; someone else voted you down. I voted this up in fact. While I disagreed with your tone and approach here on comments that the moderator subsequently removed, it's not worth a "feud". I will always match positivity like for like on any other questions.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that and agree.  Your book is great, working through it daily.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple Java question. Installing a package does nothing per se that affects your `javac` command. You always need to include all classes needed by the compilation in its `-cp` argument.

Much easier is to use a build system, like an IDE, or Maven, where you can import the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mahout` command to get its `classpath`, but sometimes it gives additional information. You can change file `$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout` to make it work.

```
javac -cp `mahout classpath` File.java -d classes
```